# How an interface implements an interface in android

Tags: android, interface

if an interface cannot implement an interface then how SpinnerAdapter interface implements Adapter interface in android

Comment: see the [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.java)

Comment: SpinnerAdatper(interface) extends Adapter(interface) not implement

Comment: in the android develpers page it is given that it imlements

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

It is extending not implementing

```
public interface SpinnerAdapter extends Adapter
```

when you implement you have to provide bodies for all methods!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html

Comment: you can check on the above link